# where to set Image Mapping to Extend mode in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, image

In Blender Internal it is located here:
[image]

I can't find that anywhere in Cycles.

Comment: Does the mapping node accomplish what you are looking for using the min and max checkboxes.

Comment: I have a Texture Coordinate Node already, how can I make these work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my self compiled Blender from today I have Clip, Extend and Repeat in the image texture node. In 2.75 it's not present yet, though. You can try a development version from [Blender buildbot](https://builder.blender.org/download/), or for extend you can use the mapping node, as PGmath said, like this:

[image]

Comment: It's our policy to give the person who answered in the comments a day or two to write an answer before posting one of your own.  See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments).

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry, I didn't know that. I should have read the meta. What can I do to set things right?

Comment: No problem, you're fine. :)  Just keep it in mind for future reference.